# Simulating gps movement on real iOS device

Tags: ios, testing, simulation, core-location

I've seen a few questions on this but none explain how to do my specific scenario:

I need to test my app works for tracking a user's location over long distances. I'm using a 3rd party to test it, so I need a way for them to simulate like they are actually moving without really moving at all or leaving their home. I was hoping to do this using a GPX or KML file that I have pre-recorded for a few routes to simulate. I really want it to be some script or app that "replays" the GPX or KML lat/long sequence on the physical device but is not actually part of my app so I can be sure app is unaware that the data is fake. I've seen apps in the App Store that let you change to a single point on a map, but I really want something that will let me replay a sequence.

Comment: If the third party is running under the Xcode debugger then they can simulate location using a Gpx file using the debugger. If they aren't then you will need to build the simulation capability into your app.

Comment: @paulw11: could I build a separate app to do it?

Comment: No.  Think of the mayhem that could arise if an app was allowed to inject false location data to other apps

Comment: @paulw11: I totally agree, I'm just puzzled how apps like "Fake Location" and "Location Spoofer" work in that case. Thank you very much for your help btw.

Comment: It looks like those apps just create map images with a fake location icon that you can post, so the fake location is just with their own app.